# About the specifications of googlefit step count management

Tags: android

I am developing an app that obtains step counts from GoogleFit, but if anyone knows the specifications of GoogleFit below, could you please tell me?

①When linking the Google Fit app with a wearable device such as Fitbit, please let me know the specifications for managing step counts within Google Fit.
For example, if you connect Fitbit to GoogleFit using the fittofit app,
The step count details on the GoogleFit app do not specifically display "fitbit" or "fittofit," so I wonder if the step count is being measured by the device itself.
I don't know if it's a Fitbit.
Also, if you link your step count with another device Xiaomi's linked app "Mifit", the measurement source will also be displayed on "Mifit" and Google Fit.
Could you please tell me the specifications, such as the conditions for whether or not the measurement source is displayed?

② There is a time lag between measuring steps and reflecting them in the GoogleFit app.
In some cases, it may take more than 10 minutes for the changes to be reflected.
What is the maximum time this will occur?
Also, why does this time lag occur?

③Please tell me the setting specifications for GoogleFit's deviceType.
Used to determine which deviceType data to obtain.
*WearOS is a wearable, and apps that link with other wearables (FittoFit, etc.)
It is linked as an app, etc.
Description of the device type above (I would like to know the official device type for wearables etc.)

I asked other communities, but I couldn't find a solution.